# Positioning webpage inside android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to show a webpage inside an android webview. But i dont want to show the navigation header of the webpage. I want to display the webpage from middle of the page or maybe starting from any divs in the page. Any help?

Comment: I don't honestly know about the implementation with this on Android, but I know that with Java you can use a BufferedReader to break apart the URL's html. I have actually done this with Java as a simple url crawler project. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html it might at least get you in the right direction.

Comment: Another option could be to use javascript commands inside of an onPageFinished method to delete the components of the webpage that you dont want.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. Actually i found another method to fix this. In case any one is looking for something similar. This is what i did. I just created the native app header and sized to overlay on top of the webpage header through layout xml. That way you wont see the webpage header in the webview.. Appreciate all your help